# The difference between we proceeded and we have proceeded to

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality

I would like to know the difference between we have proceeded to study something and we proceeded to study something knowing that this action was already finished in last time.

Which one is correct and would be written in scientific article ?

Comment: This is a question more suited to ELL. There is probably an existing question already of which it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. One refers to a past action. The other refers to an action as if it  had just now been completed.  Both are possible.

When describing a step-by-step process *as if* it were happening in real time, as a guide to instruct someone who will be attempting to repeat the procedure, we can use the present perfect and the present:

> When we have blended the eggs with the milk, we add the vanilla.

That is, we add the vanilla after we have blended the eggs with the milk. (You are saying, in effect, that is how it is done and you should do the same when following this recipe. )

But if you wish to describe what you *did*, as a simple record of what happened, you would use the simple past and past perfect:

> When we had blended the eggs with the milk, we added the vanilla.

That is, we added the vanilla after we had blended the eggs with the milk.

So, you need to decide whether you wish to present a simple record of what you did or actively instruct others how to repeat the steps you took.  In scientific papers, a simple record is the usual choice, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

You couldn't describe the past tense If you feel a scope in your scientific research. The choice is yours, what would you feel?